# Find matching string in workbook, copy entire row from different worksheet and replace original row - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, string-matching

I'm looking to loop through the entire workbook and find matching strings from "Sheet1, ColumnA" in "Sheet3, ColumnA" and copy the entire row from "Sheet3, ColumnB" back to matching location in "Sheet1". "Sheet1" would be used as an organized view and "Sheet3" would be used as an input sheet. The idea is to copy exported values into "Sheet3" to have "Sheet1" automatically update without the need of manual copy/paste.

**Sheet1**
[Sheet1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgdu6.jpg)

**Sheet3**
[Sheet3 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1y4B.jpg)

**Updated Sheet1**
[Updated Sheet1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc7te.jpg)

I'm new to VBA but was able to create a check for matching values and making the matches "Bold". Maybe I just need some modifications?

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Declare variables
    Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean
       
       'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
       iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       
       'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
       For iRow = 1 To iRowL
          'For every cell that is not empty, search through the first column in each worksheet in the
          'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.

          If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
             For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
                bln = False
                var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)
                
                'If you find a matching value, indicate success by setting bln to true and exit the loop;
                'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
                If Not IsError(var) Then
                   bln = True
                   Exit For
                End If
             Next iSheet
          End If
          
          'If you do not find a matching value, do not bold the value in the original list;
          'if you do find a value, bold it.
          If bln = False Then
             Cells(iRow, 1).Font.Bold = False
             Else
             Cells(iRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
          End If
       Next iRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have modified your code to do what I understand it is you want to do (see below).
Have also made other changes and provided reasoning in the comments.
Hope this answers your question, as well and providing other useful information.

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    
''' Declare variables:
''' o It's good practice to specify (in you own parlance) the data type in the variable name
''' o  Some use a one character, I prefer two characters.
''' o  Your Dim here uses one character, but incorrectly uses 'i' (used for integer) for longs
    ' Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean
    
''' Also, you can specify data types using a symbol 'as short-hand' for the common data types
''' o  Variants don't need 'as Variant' and you can use: % for integer, # for double, & for long, $ for string.
''' I also tend to abbreviate (what I consider self-evident) terms (e.g. Row to R, Last Row to LR)

''' All up, I'd suggest the following:
    Dim inSh%, lgR&, lgLR&, blFlag As Boolean, vnVal, vnMatchedR
       
''' Speed things up with screen and calculation off
    With Application: .Calculation = xlCalculationManual: .ScreenUpdating = False: End With
       
''' Get last data row (last row in the active sheet, with any data in column 1)
    lgLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
''' Cycle through the cells in that column:
''' o  I changed this to ignore the headings. Revert to 1 if you want to copy headings as well:
    For lgR = 2 To lgLR: vnVal = Cells(lgR, 1)
       
       'For every cell that is not empty, search through the first column in each worksheet in the
       'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.

    ''' Empty cell values (nulls) = a zero-length string
        If vnVal <> "" Then
            For inSh = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(inSh)
                vnMatchedR = Application.Match(vnVal, .Columns(1), 0)
                
            ''' If matched: Copy the row from the activesheet to the matched row
                If Not IsError(vnMatchedR) Then
                    
                ''' Here I am transfering the entire row's values only (not row heights, formats, etc.)
                    .Rows(vnMatchedR).EntireRow.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(lgR, 1).EntireRow.Value

                ''' If your text is taken literally (i.e. copy the row),
                ''' then you want this instead of the above:
                    'ActiveSheet.Cells(lgR, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                    '.Rows(vnMatchedR).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                End If
            End With
          
          Next inSh
       End If
    
    Next lgR
    
''' Reinstate screen and calculation
    With Application: .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: .ScreenUpdating = False: End With
End Sub
```